# Bash loop won't stop looping

Tags: json, bash, if-statement, while-loop, jq

I have a JSON blob structured as such:

```
{
    "total_items": 2371,
    "page_count": 3,
    "items": [
        {
            "landing_id": "503a654cfaf5614b2069de304dbdb3c9",
            "token": "503a654cfaf5614b2069de304dbdb3c9",
            "response_id": "503a654cfaf5614b2069de304dbdb3c9",
            "landed_at": "2019-03-07T18:35:06Z",
            "submitted_at": "2019-03-07T18:36:17Z",
            "metadata": {
                "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.2 Safari/605.1.15",
                "platform": "other",
                "network_id": "321c8d9867",
                "browser": "default"
            },
            "answers": [
                {
                    "field": {
                        "id": "uqZV4j2RSapJ",
                        "type": "opinion_scale",
                        "ref": "bed55d05-b5e2-46dd-af91-337519830e3e"
                    },
                    "type": "number",
                    "number": 5
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "landing_id": "b9d50e6734d30753de42b78a2ad5d741",
            "token": "b9d50e6734d30753de42b78a2ad5d741",
            "response_id": "b9d50e6734d30753de42b78a2ad5d741",
            "landed_at": "2019-03-07T18:12:29Z",
            "submitted_at": "2019-03-07T18:13:54Z",
            "metadata": {
                "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
                "platform": "mobile",
                "network_id": "3a74e2b874",
                "browser": "touch"
            },
            "answers": [
                {
                    "field": {
                        "id": "uqZV4j2RSapJ",
                        "type": "opinion_scale",
                        "ref": "bed55d05-b5e2-46dd-af91-337519830e3e"
                    },
                    "type": "number",
                    "number": 1
                },
                {
                    "field": {
                        "id": "v8nQgm61VdLp",
                        "type": "dropdown",
                        "ref": "d20b5f19-dc7c-4497-b798-239924054367"
                    },
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Inconsistent information"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "landing_id": "96f601b5769bacf7208b1a9c8c390278",
            "token": "96f601b5769bacf7208b1a9c8c390278",
            "response_id": "96f601b5769bacf7208b1a9c8c390278",
            "landed_at": "2019-03-07T18:09:08Z",
            "submitted_at": "2019-03-07T18:09:40Z",
            "metadata": {
                "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
                "platform": "mobile",
                "network_id": "1c59eb873c",
                "browser": "touch"
            },
            "answers": [
                {
                    "field": {
                        "id": "uqZV4j2RSapJ",
                        "type": "opinion_scale",
                        "ref": "bed55d05-b5e2-46dd-af91-337519830e3e"
                    },
                    "type": "number",
                    "number": 5
                },
                {
                    "field": {
                        "id": "llTPythU272I",
                        "type": "multiple_choice",
                        "ref": "bf54c521-3749-4c80-93bf-bb5448d03b34"
                    },
                    "type": "choices",
                    "choices": {
                        "labels": [
                            "Travis"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I've put together a script that looks something like this:

```
curl https://api.xyz.com/forms/Te8Fy9/responses?page_size=1000 -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' > raw.json

page_parameter=`cat raw.json | jq -c '.items | last | .token' | tr -d '"'`

items_parameter=`cat raw.json | jq -c '.total_items'`

cat raw.json | jq -c '.items[]' > clean.json

bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect bq-test:sandox.test clean.json

while [[ ${#items_parameter} -gt 0 ]]
do

    curl 'https://api.xyz.com/forms/Te8Fy9/responses?page_size=1000&after='${page_parameter} -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' > raw.json

    page_parameter=`cat returns_raw.json | jq -c '.items | last | .token' | tr -d '"'`

    items_parameter=`cat returns_raw.json | jq -c '.total_items'`

    cat returns_raw.json | jq -c '.items[]' > clean.json

    if [[  ${#items_parameter} -gt 0 ]]; then

        bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect bq-test:sandox.test clean.json

    fi

done
```

So what I want it to do is:

1.) Run the API call (`curl https...`), store as `raw.json`

2.) Store a specified value, the last value of `token`, as a parameter. In this example that value would be `96f601b5769bacf7208b1a9c8c390278` and stored as `page_parameter`

3.) Store another specified value, the value associated with `total_items` at the top. In this examople, that value is `2371` and stored as `items_parameter`

4.) Use `jq -c '.items[]'` to clean `raw.json` and create that as `clean.json`

5.) Push to BigQuery

6.) Assuming it's run correctly, it should produce an `items_parameter` greater than 0, which if that's the case, take the value of `page_parameter` to iterate through the subsuqent `curl` command to pull the next 1000 records

7.) Repeat step #2 (`page_parameter`), step #3 (`items_parameter`), and step #4 (clean `raw.json` and save as `clean.json`)

8.) IF the `items_parameter` value is greater than 0, THEN load it to BigQuery

So the hope is that it would do that until that value equals 0, in which point, it would break out of the loop. But it's not doing that. It just continuously iterates over the same records.

In theory, it should run three different cycles of records which are loaded: 1 - 1000, 1001 - 2000, 2001-2371, and then break it off.

What am I missing? I think I'm pretty close and likely just doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: [Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script. This will make it show all the statements as they're executed, and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: `${#foo}` is checking the *length* of string `foo`. A string containing the number `0` has a length of `1`, so unless your `items_parameter` is not *zero* but *empty*, you'll never exit your loop.

Comment: BTW, `tr -d '"'` after `jq` is generally a sign that you should be using `jq -r`.

Comment: (Then again, you should probably be using `IFS=$'\t' read -r page_parameter items_parameter < <(jq -r '[(.items | last | .token), .total_items] | @tsv' <returns_raw.json` to read *both* variables from *one* `jq` invocation, and avoid the unnecessary/useless `cat`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a simple typo: you're outputting the result of the curl as `raw.json` but using `cat returns_raw.json` as the input to your further JQ commands. If you fix the file name in all places, does it start working?